# How does Magento create SQL query to load an EAV model that has an integer and a varchar filter value?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am looking forward to developing an understanding of how Magento's ORM breaks down a query filter to actual SQL to run the query to fetch EAV data for a model (say category)?

Answer (score 1):

In magento it is common to use *collections* to load data from database. Collections offer methods like *addAttributeToFilter()*. Using those you can specify which rows you want to actually load. In the background magento is building the SQL query while considering the EAV model. Once you *load()* the collection, the SQL query is actually executed on the database.

Example: you want to load products with the attribute *my_att* and the value *my_val*. First step is to get the collection:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

Now you can filter for the attribute:

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('my_att', array('eq' => 'my_val'));
```

To understand what is happening you can get the actual SQL query magento built for you with:

```
(string)$productCollection->getSelect();
```

As you can see magento built the SQL query considering the EAV model (joining the correct tables like *catalog_product_entity_varchar*). For more info about the EAV model and how attributes are organized in magento I highly recommend the certification study guide (http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Certification-Study-Guide-MCD-v1.pdf).

Comment: @Idrees whats the status? Did you check out the study guide for more info?